# Remove 'required' from checkbox when an input is filled with jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

So im doing a contact form with several text inputs and checkboxes and validating with the jQuery Validate plugin, and what i want to achieve is this:

[image: screenshot of my contact form]

When the text input is filled, the 'required' attribute from the rules of the plugin aplied on the checkboxes get removed.

This is my HTML(inside a bootstrap modal:

```
<div id="invitoUno" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="height: 0; border-bottom: none;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row form-invito">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <form method="post" action="solicitudinvito.php" id="invitoform" name="invitoform">
                            <h6>Nombre completo:</h6>
                            <div class='cb-input'>
                                <input id='nombre' type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class='cb-input'>
                                <input type="text" value="Fam. de Luis Arturo Garza Bassoco" id="persona" name="persona" hidden>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                                    <h6>Celular:</h6>
                                    <div class='cb-input'>
                                        <input id='celular' type="text" name="celular" placeholder="" required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                                    <h6>Teléfono de casa (opcional):</h6>
                                    <div class='cb-input'>
                                        <input id='telcasa' type="text" name="telcasa" placeholder="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                    <h6>¿Requieres de recibo deducible de impuestos?:
                                <label style="padding-left: 20px;">Sí</label>

                                <input type="checkbox" class="factura option-input checkbox" name="factura" value="Requiere factura" required />
                                <!--   -->
                                <label style="padding-left: 20px;">No</label>

                                <input type="checkbox" class="factura option-input checkbox" name="factura" value="No requiere factura" placeholder="" required />
                                <!--   -->
                            </h6>
                            <br>
                            <h4 style="padding-bottom:5px;">deseo invitarle la despensa a:</h4>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                                    <span style="color:#5C5B5F; font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;">1 familia</span><br>
                                    <span class="cantidad">$160.00</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="familia option-input checkbox" style="top:10%;" name="familia" value="Apoya una familia = $160.00" placeholder="" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                                    <span style="color:#5C5B5F; font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;">2 familias</span><br>
                                    <span class="cantidad">$320.00</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="familia option-input checkbox" style="top:10%;" name="familia" value="Apoya dos familias = $320.00" placeholder="" required />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                                    <h6 style="color:#FFBA00;">Otra cantidad:</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                                    <div class='cb-input' style="margin-top: -10px;">
                                        <input id='otrafamilia' type="text" name="familia" placeholder="$" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <h4 style="padding-bottom:5px;">Aportación empresa mensual:</h4>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 col-12">
                                    <span class="cantidad">$1,000.00</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="aportacion option-input checkbox" style="top:10%;" name="empresa" value="Aportacion mensual de $1000.00" placeholder="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                                    <h6 style="color:#FFBA00;">Otra cantidad:</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
                                    <div class='cb-input' style="margin-top: -10px;">
                                        <input id='empresaotra' type="text" name="empresa" placeholder="$" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 text-center" style="box-shadow: none; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                                <label class="acepto" style="padding-left: 20px;">Acepto el compromiso con Banco de Alimentos de Los Mochis I.A.P.</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="option-input checkbox" name="compromiso" value="Acepto el compromiso con Banco de Alimentos de Los Mochis I.A.P." required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 text-center" style="padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                <button class="btn-amarillo" type="submit" id="submit">envíar</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this are the rules:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#celular').mask('(000) 000-0000');
        $('.success').fadeOut(0);
        var v = $("#invitoform").validate({
            rules: {
                nombre: {
                    required: true
                },
                celular: {
                    required: true
                },
                factura: {
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 1 
                },
                familia: {
                    required: true
                },
                empresa: {
                    required: true
                },
                compromiso: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                nombre: {
                    required: "Debes escribir tu(s) nombre(s) y apellido(s).",
                },
                celular: {
                    required: "Debes de escribir tu número de teléfono.",
                    minlength: "El número que ingresaste no es válido."
                },
                factura: {
                    required: "Debes elegir una opción."
                },
                familia: {
                    required: "Debes de elegir una opción o escribir una cantidad."
                },
                empresa: {
                    required: "Debes de elegir una opción o escribir una cantidad."
                },
                compromiso: {
                    required: "Necesitas aceptar tu compromiso con nosotros antes de continuar."
                }
            }

        })
    });
</script>
```

Despite they have the same name (the 2 checkboxes and text input) the rule "required" doesn't seem to work because when i fill the input one of the checkboxes are still needed to continue.

Comment: You can't have a checkbox and a text box share the same `name` attribute!  That makes no sense and the plugin is going to ignore one of them.

Comment: @Sparky ok, im gonna change that :) still i need to remove the required from checkboxes if that text box is filled, and return the attribute if don't.

Comment: posted an answer below explaining how to do it.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you so much for helping me!! But now i have a new problem: when you check one of the checkboxes i can't send the form because the input idk why is required : (

Comment: I have no idea what you did wrong.  Why not construct a jsFiddle demo for us to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Despite they have the same name (the 2 checkboxes and text input) the rule "required" doesn't seem to work because when i fill the input one of the checkboxes are still needed to continue."*

What?  You put the same `name` on checkboxes and text elements?  That does not even make any sense and it will just ignore the second instance.

First, fix the `name` attributes so they are unique.  Only that grouping of checkboxes can have the same `name`.

Second, if you want to change rules based on some dynamic condition, then you would put conditional functions in place of rule declarations.

```
rules: {
    ....
    empresa_checkbox: {
        required: {
            depends: function() {
                // checkbox only required when text field is empty
                return $('input[name="empresa_text"]').is(':blank');
            }
        }
    },
    empresa_text: {
        required: {
            depends: function() {
                // text box only required when checkbox is unchecked
                return $('input[name="empresa_checkbox"]').is(':unchecked');
            }
        }
    },
    ....             
},
```

And finally, you do NOT need the HTML5 `required` attribute on any elements since you're declaring your rules within the `.validate()` method.  You should remove those permanently to ensure they don't interfere or cause confusion.